# Difference between new Date() and firestore new Date() data

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

For a new app I want to know the time between the start and end of a run.

At the start I save a timestamp with the new Date() function in Firebase. (I'm using this function and not firestore fieldValue because the stamps can't fight with other users making stamps at the same moment.

Before definitely ending the run I want an overview of the difference in time between start and end.

I take the start value from firebase, and I make a temporary end value with the new Date() function.

When I put those 2 values next to each other it seems firestore changes the value when it's written in the database.

When I write the endStamp also in firebase and use this value for the calculation, it all works fine.

This is my code right now:

```
calculateTimeBetweenStamps(run) {
      const startTime = run.startTimestamp;
      const endTime = new Date();
      return calculateTimeBetweenStamps({
        startTime: startTime,
        endTime: endTime
      });
    }
```

Js file that includes the function:

```
export function calculateTimeBetweenStamps(e) {
  const startTime = e.startTime;
  const endTime = e.endTime;
  var difference = endTime - startTime;

  var sec_num = parseInt(difference, 10);
  var hours = Math.floor(sec_num / 3600);
  var minutes = Math.floor((sec_num - hours * 3600) / 60);
  var seconds = sec_num - hours * 3600 - minutes * 60;

  if (hours < 10) {
    hours = "0" + hours;
  }
  if (minutes < 10) {
    minutes = "0" + minutes;
  }
  if (seconds < 10) {
    seconds = "0" + seconds;
  }
  return `${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firestore uses JavaScript Date object, same as your code, however it has a limitation as you can see in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types):

> When stored in Cloud Firestore, precise only to microseconds; any additional precision is rounded down.

This might be the difference in the dates that you are experiencing. If you need this level of granularity you can use only Timestamps in Firestore, since as you can see in it's [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp#todate):

> represents a point in time independent of any time zone or calendar, represented as seconds and fractions of seconds at nanosecond resolution in UTC Epoch time.

And then to operate it in your code you can covert it to date with it's `.toDate()` function, which will return you again a JavaScript Date object but without precision being rounded up.

Comment: @Rafeal Thanks for you response! the toDate() function on the firebase stamp was the sollution :)